# Network Engineering Stack Exchange on Slashdot

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I submitted an announcement for our site to slashdot.org:

[Network Engineering Q&A Site Launched](http://tech.slashdot.org/story/13/05/26/1243208/network-engineering-qa-site-launched)

It's now on the frontpage, on top of the stories:

[image: slashdot screenshot]

I hope for a nice discussion also there and for new users. Feel free to comment there, to upvote what you think is good, and to share the link. Your comments there can convince new users too!

Comment: now we know who to blame for [this](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1267/what-i-got-is-modem-router-combo-how-may-i-use-the-router-functionality-alone-in). IT'S YOU. :-) Thanks for doing this though. Hopefully people will read the FAQ before posting.

Comment: Time for a new Meta question - Are meta questions that aren't actually questions, just "look at what I did" allowed here? :)

Comment: @javano This meta site is for discussion how to improve the site and also about doing site promotion. This post informs about one and invites our users to join the discussion there. And should be an example what we can do for site promotion. Where else should I post this information four our users? We don't have a blog yet. And btw. I posted also some links to Hacker News, without mentioning. Well, I can think about changing it to a question.

Comment: @Stefan I think you may have been slightly offended by what was simply a joke from me :) Also, if promotion really is for discussion here, why not start a question called something like "NE Promotion" and post you Slashdot/Hackernews efforts there, so that everyone can see this, and others can post their promotional input too, so that no one overlaps.

Comment: @javano Good idea! I like jokes, it seems sometimes it happens that I don't recognize one. :-)

Comment: My 19-year nephew who's getting into technology told me about this new SE site the other day, but I hadn't told him.  He read it on /.

Comment: I have to say thanks to all the regular experts and commentators here on NE... It's you guys that keep the dribble out unlike the comments that I waded through on Slashdot (many of whom appear to believe that the South Park episode showing a large Linksys router as *the* Internet is accurate).  Comments like "network professionals are going the way of the dodo" illustrate the trouble we have in conveying the complexity, engineering, and professionalism required to keep their bits moving.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I heard about this site, and it looks very interesting.